# FindByIdentity - performance differences

Tags: .net, iis-7, directoryservices

The following code works fine from a variety of machines on our domain.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, @"domain\username")
```

However, if I run this similar code on a machine that is not on a domain, it works but the FindByIdentity line takes 2+ seconds.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, @"machinename\username")
```

**Can this performance difference be addressed by supplying special parameters to the PrincipalContext constructor and/or the FindByIdentity method?  Is there a setting in IIS or Windows that could be tweaked?**

**At the very least, can anybody tell me why it might be slower in the second scenario?**

The code is running from an ASP.NET MVC 3 app hosted in IIS 7.5 (Integrated Pipeline) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: If you are familiar with Network Monitor or Wireshark, you can capture network packets to see how long it takes to talk to the domain controllers each time this query is executed. That can give you some hint. This is only an active directory side issue, nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Only peculiar thing is that it's faster with a domain controller.  The slow environment is workgroup only so it shouldn't be reaching out to anything.  I can try out Wireshark to see if I spot anything unusual though.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem. Try the below block of code.  I don't know why but it's much faster (ignore first time slow login after build in VS - subsequent logins are speedy).  See similar SO question [Why would using PrincipalSearcher be faster than FindByIdentity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799457/why-would-using-principalsearcher-be-faster-than-findbyidentity)

```
var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine );
var user = new UserPrincipal(context);
user.SamAccountName = username;
var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
user = searcher.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
```

The underlying issue may have something to do with netBios calls.  See [ADLDS very slow (roundtrip to \Server*\MAILSLOT\NET\NETLOGON)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winserverDS/thread/20eb50e9-3e68-4d29-bcdd-a4fc166b9c00)

Comment: Note that `PrincipalContext`, `UserPrincipal` and also `PrincipalSearcher` implement **IDisposable**. You should put a few `usings()` here...

Comment: Thy for this solution, my Performance went from 40 sec to 3 sec.
Works perfect ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even with JimSTAT's answer being quite old, it led me into the right direction solving my problem.
I would like to point out that disabling `NetBIOS over TCP/IP` on all my Hyper-V-Switch network interfaces eliminated every delay I had experienced beforehand. Every call to `PrincipalContext()`, `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` and `UserPrincipal.GetGroups()` is down to 10 ms or lower, from well above 10,000 ms. It appears to me that every virtual network card was being queried which took a felt century to time out. Lucky me I found this post!