# Why would using PrincipalSearcher be faster than FindByIdentity()?

Tags: c#, .net, security, azure, windows-server-2008

I had this code:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine );
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, username );
```

and it took about 2-3 seconds to run. I was recommended to rewrite it using `PrincipalSearcher` class:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine );
var user = new UserPrincipal(context);
user.SamAccountName = username;
var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
user = searcher.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
```

and it runs in less than one second - notably faster. The person why advised the rewrite is as clueless as me why it runs faster.

Why does it make any performance difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673947/932282

Answer (score 5):

The only plausible reason I can think of is that `.FindByIdentity` has to check multiple attributes for a match, since you're not specifying exactly which attribute you're looking for.

You can do that by specifying the attribute you're looking for ([using this method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx)) - try this for a comparison:

```
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
```

How fast is this?

Comment: Interesting, code using three-pararemeters `FindByIdentity()` works a bit slower than the original `FindByIdentity()`.

Comment: Maybe algorithm implementation differences?